# Unable to call required method from relevant class

Tags: java, methods

I have a task where I need to create a program for "TotalCompetitions", which consists of multiple "Competition". I need to create an application which allows user to do various options related to TotalCompetition.

If the first option ("Create a new competition") is selected, by typing "1" and then pressing Enter,
the program should call the addNewCompetition method of the TotalCompetitions class to add
a new competition with a given name. After creating a new competition, the program should goes
back to the main menu.

The second option is to add entries to the competition. However, when I try to call the addEntry() method located in the Competition class to the newly created competition, it doesn't work as it is still of TotalCompetitions type. How can I access the newly created competition to access the required method?

At the moment, this is my code:

```
public class TotalCompetitions {
    private ArrayList<Competition> competitions;

    
    public TotalCompetitions() {
        this.competitions = new ArrayList<Competition>();

    }

    public ArrayList<Competition> getCompetitions() {
        return competitions;
    }

    public void setCompetitions(ArrayList<Competition> competitions) {
        this.competitions = competitions;
    }

    
    public Competition addNewCompetition(String name, int id) {
        Competition newCompetition = new Competition(name, id);
        return newCompetition;
    }
}
```

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        TotalCompetitions sc = new TotalCompetitions();
        int competitionId = 0;

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Please select an option. Type 5 to exit.");
            System.out.println("1. Create a new competition");
            System.out.println("2. Add new entries");
            System.out.println("3. Draw winners");
            System.out.println("4. Get a summary report");
            System.out.println("5. Exit");
            
            String command = keyboard.next();
            
            
            if (command.equals("1")) {
                    keyboard.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Competition name:");
                    String name = keyboard.nextLine();
                    competitionId += 1;
                    sc.addNewCompetition(name, competitionId);
                    System.out.println("A new competition has been created!");
                    System.out.println("Competition ID: " + competitionId + ", Competition Name: " + name);
            }
            else if (command.equals("2")) {
                    sc.addEntry();
            }
            else if (command.equals("5")) {
                    System.out.println("The end");
                    break;
            }
}
```

Comment: Does this even compile: `TotalCompetitions sc = new SimpleCompetitions();`? What is `SimpleCompetitions` and how is it related to `TotalCompetitions`? Where is that class defined?

Comment: oops my bad, this is a typo. Should be ```TotalCompetitions sc = new TotalCompetitions();``` I have edited the original post now

Answer (score 0):

`sc.addNewCompetition(name, competitionId);` returns a new object of the type `Competition`, however, this new object is not used by your program. The variable `sc` is still of the type `TotalCompetition` which is not related to the type `Competition`. Furthermore, your method `addNewCompetition(String id, int id)` does not add the new Object to the ArrayList. The solution would be to store the object which is returned by the `sc.addNewCompetition(...)` call and call `addEntry()` on this object.

Comment: I replaced this bit ```sc.addNewCompetition(name, competitionId);``` to ```Competition comp = sc.addNewCompetition(name, competitionId);```. However, when I try to call ```comp.addEntry()``` it says it cannot be resolved and asks me to create local variable comp.

Comment: Make sure that the ```comp```-variable is not inisde of the first if-clause because it cannot be called from the second if-clause in this case. Create a new object of the type ```Competition``` before the while loop and store the return value from ```sc.addNewCompetition()``` in this variable.